Does "bustle about" mean the same thing as "fluster about"?
I'm not sure about the exact meaning of the verb "fluster" in the video game Fallout 3 (American game).

All these confounded people fluster about like I'm made of
eggshells and about to fall to pieces at any moment. I'm surprised
they even let you in.

I've never heard of "fluster" being used this way. I mostly hear it as an adjective e.g. "he is flustered" (meaning "upset"). When I was searching for an appropriate definition I found one that lists "to bustle" as a synonym:

"fluster" (verb) To be agitated and confused; to bustle.
He seemed to fluster when speaking in front of many people. (Wiktionary)

Does "All these confounded people fluster about" mean the same thing as "All these confounded people bustle about" based on the Wiktionary definition for bustle, below?

"bustle" To move busily and energetically with fussiness (often followed by
about).  
The commuters bustled about inside the train station. (Wiktionary)


I've never heard anyone use the phrase "fluster about". It sounds like something Aunt Bee might have said on The Andy Griffith Show in the 1960s.

In context it suggests that the speaker's fragile state ("like I'm made of eggshells") has put the caregivers into a state of nervous agitation.

Perhaps fluster about is a misspelling of flutter about.

Fluster about is not a standard usage. The dictionary meaning of fluster is 'to put someone in a state of nervous confusion' - to cause them to feel 'flustered'. It's not normally an intransitive verb. Presumably the writer meant that the people behave as though they are flustered.
Bustle suggests to me busy, purposeful activity - not the same as being flustered.

Thank you for your answer, do you think it was a mistake on the Wiktionary's part to include "bustle" as a synonym? Also, something I failed to include in my initial post is that "fluster" can be an intransitive verb which means:
v. intr.
To become agitated, excited, or confused: a shy student who flusters easily.  (Could this be a possible meaning here. This would mean that people become agitated around him.)

Well, I would not consider bustle to be a synonym of fluster. As for the writer's meaning, your guess is as good as mine.

I wonder if fluster here isn’t something like fuss and bustle and blunder all smushed up into one. // @StaticBounce That intransitive meaning is really a type of anticausative change-of-state verb, which is a specific subtype of intransitive verbs that can sometimes be productively derived from the transitive base. Verbs that denote putting someone into a certain state can often do this (‘she discombobulates easily’ works all right), but not always (‘she enrages easily’ is questionable at best).

Wiktionary has an obsolete chain of words from "fluster" to "bluster" (somewhat reasonable). Bluster and bustle have totally different meanings.

@JanusBahsJacquet: Besides those, flutter and bluster are also close at hand.  Fluster about is a malapropism, but an effective and evocative one (and most probably deliberate, by the game writers).

'Fluster about' suggests manic, worried activity - someone being worried at the author and doing a lot of things that don't necessarily help. In the Fallout quote, people are 'flustering about' a presumably old or frail person because they're worried about them and/or trying to curry favour.
'Bustle about' suggests more purposeful and confident activity (such as people at a train station going to their platform, a crowd at a market, or chefs moving around a kitchen). So they're similar phrases on the surface level in that they denote a lot of activity, but the former denotes anxiety in a way that the latter does not.

Oddly, my instincts tell me I'd describe a home cook, or someone cooking for guests, as "bustling about", but I wouldn't describe a professional restaurant kitchen crew in the same way. I think bustling indicates a certain level of... mellowness, while still being purposeful and direct.

@ConnieMnemonic I think bustling is a great description for a busy restaurant kitchen.

@barbecue Again interesting. I'd be open to describing the kitchen as "bustling", but I'd feel slightly weird about describing the head chef as "bustling about."

@ConnieMnemonic That I would agree with. Chefs tend to bristle rather than bustle.

@barbecue Hah, exactly so! Well said, heh heh.
